# Returning the Key with the highest Value from a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> In this problem, you'll do the same thing, but with a more
> complex data structure. Your function should be called
> most_active, and it should have one parameter.
>
> Instead of a dictionary, your parameter is a list of
> dictionaries. Every dictionary in the list will have exactly
> two keys: 'name' and 'days_active'. Your goal, as before,
> is to return the name of the most active student.
>
> Some of the code you wrote on the previous problem will be
> reusable, but you'll need to modify it.
>
> Hint: you do NOT need to iterate over the keys in the
> dictionaries inside the lists. You can always just access
> `the_dict["name"]` and `the_dict["days_active"]` directly.
> Your only loop should be the loop over the list.

```
#Add your code here!

def most_active(the_list):
    max_active = (max(the_list, key=lambda x: (["days_active"])))
    return max_active
```

> Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
> You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
> function with different inputs.
>
> If your function works correctly, this will originally
> print:
> Chopra, Deepak

```
the_list = [{"name": "Joyner, David", "days_active": 14},
            {"name": "Chopra, Deepak", "days_active": 22},
            {"name": "Winfrey, Oprah", "days_active": 17}]
print(most_active(the_list))
```

Currently my code returns the following: `{'name': 'Joyner, David', 'days_active': 14}`
I have been working on this since yesterday and have tried many "solutions" but this is the closest I have gotten. Also, I have searched and searched on every conceivable forum and can't seem to figure this out...any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `max(the_list, key=lambda x: x["days_active"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
def most_active(the_list):
    return max(the_list, key=lambda x: x["days_active"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this below,

```
the_list = [{"name": "Joyner, David", "days_active": 14},
            {"name": "Chopra, Deepak", "days_active": 22},
            {"name": "Winfrey, Oprah", "days_active": 17}]

print(max(the_list, key=lambda k: k['days_active']))
```

output will be

```
{'name': 'Chopra, Deepak', 'days_active': 22}
```

editing it, sorry didn't notice
`@Johnny Mopp`s comment. Thanks for the comment anyway

Comment: It's fine to post an answer even if it is similar to a comment. Answers are preferred to comments - I'm just too lazy to type one up.

Comment: hey @JohnnyMopp, really appreciate your broad mind here !!